# Переход по ссылке, заданной в label

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. У меня такая ситуация: в приложении под iOS пользователь при помощи кнопок задает значение UILabel, нужно чтобы при нажатии еще одной кнопки выполнялся переход по интернет-адресу, который и является содержимым label. Но я неожиданно понял, что не знаю, как выполнить такой переход. У меня написан такой код:

```
- (IBAction)setToOneButton:(id)sender
{
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
}

- (IBAction)setToTwoButton:(id)sender
{
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"]];
}

- (IBAction)setToThreeButton:(id)sender
{
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"]];
}

- (IBAction)goButton:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@" "]];
}
```

Надеюсь на помощь, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(IBAction)goButton:(id)sender 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_label.text]]; 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, как же я сам не понял! Спасибо огромное!